# Jenkins-slave in Kubernetes gives 404 error

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

```
Agent successfully connected and online
```

I've set up Kubernetes. There is 1 jenkins master and when I start a job it's creating a temporary jenkins slave.

It seems to work fine. The slave starts and is connected. The job (just an '`echo`' runs fine. But after that I see the following error in my Jenkins-slave logs. What's the reason for this?

```
JNLP agent connected from 10.xx.xxx.xxx/10.xx.xxx.xxx
Slave.jar version: 3.10
Slave.jar version: 3.10
This is a Unix agent
NOTE: Relative remote path resolved to: /home/jenkins
This is a Unix agent
NOTE: Relative remote path resolved to: /home/jenkins

Agent successfully connected and online






HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /computer/jenkins-slave-5hxzz/logText/progressiveHtml. Reason:

    Not Found
```

Is this because the slave is already shutted down (after running the job)?

Comment: There is a similar issue with Mesos that was reported a while back. It looks like the resolution had to do with ports being blocked on the server. 

https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin/issues/77

Are you able to access the Master on the correct IP:Port from the machine where the slave is running?

Comment: The Jenkins slave is on-demand to create and shutdown after complete the job. This error seems to check the Slave job progress.